# Using "this" in an addEventListener to replace "document.querySelector()"

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, addeventlistener

Beginner in JavaScript here. I'm building a simple calculator using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
I've realized that if I use *this* instead of `document.querySelector(".add")` when adding a style to a button inside of an `addEventListener`, my code still works.

Would that be correct or should I always stick to the original `document.querySelector(".add")`?

```
document.querySelector(".add").addEventListener("click", function () {
  let a = Number(document.querySelector(".num1").value);
  let b = Number(document.querySelector(".num2").value);

  this.classList.add("botaoClicado");
  //the above "this" replaces this excerpt: document.querySelector(".add")

  let soma = a + b;
  console.log(soma);

  document.querySelector(".result").textContent = `RESULTADO: ${soma}`;
});
```

Comment: Using `this` in the context of an event listener is correct and is actually a good practice and here it is more efficient since the browser doesn't need to search for the element again.

Comment: You have had a JavaScript aha moment.

Answer (score 1):

Using `this` in an event listener refers to the element that triggered the event.

Since you're adding the event listener to the `.add` element, `this` inside the callback function refers to that `.add` element. It's perfectly fine to do so and in this case would save you some extra querySelector calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you have provided a regular Javascript function, then `this` will be set to `event.currentTarget` - which is the element you attached the event listener to.

However, you need to be careful that if you provide an arrow function expression, arrow functions do not have their own bindings to `this`. Therefore, you will need to use `event.currentTarget` instead.

```js
element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // this === event.currentTarget
})

element.addEventListener('click', event => {
  // this !== event.currentTarget
})
```

Also note that due to the way that events bubble or are 'captured' (depending on whether you specified `useCapture` when calling `addEventListener`), the event can fire when you are interacting with a parent or child of the element you attached the event listener to.

In some circumstances, you may need to check that `event.target === event.currentTarget`, in order to not have the contents of your event listener run more often than necessary. `event.target` means the element that caused the event to fire, which may be different than the element you attached the listener to.